# Paypal RefundTransaction INVOICEID Issue

Tags: paypal

I've been using the RefundTransaction method for a long time. I've successfully applied partial and full refunds using end point: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/

When I added INVOICE parameter previous week to set unique information on refund data, responses started to fail.

```
$refundArr = array(
                    'TRANSACTIONID' => $transactionId,
                    'REFUNDTYPE' => 'Partial',
                    'AMT' => $refundAmount,
                    'CURRENCYCODE' => $refundCurrency,
                    'INVOICEID' => $orderId
                );
```

Sample response is:

> {"TIMESTAMP":"2015-07-06T08:11:52Z","CORRELATIONID":"****4dee2****","ACK":"Failure","VERSION":"106.0","BUILD":"********","L_ERRORCODE0":"10001","L_SHORTMESSAGE0":"Internal
>   Error","L_LONGMESSAGE0":"The transaction could not be
>   loaded","L_SEVERITYCODE0":"Error","REFUNDSTATUS":"None","PENDINGREASON":"None"}

So I thought INVOICEID works as a conditional parameter to find original checkout transaction. Can you give me detailed information about this issue?

Best Regards

Comment: This sounds like something that PayPal might help you understand? According to their docs the InvoiceId is optional and only specific to you, but I suspect that they need the invoiceId in the original transaction if you want to use it for the refund. The error suggests that PayPal has trouble finding your transaction, probably related to searching with invoiceId.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by adding the invoice ID? It is provided in order to support non-reference refunds (in concert with payer ID). If you already have transaction ID then you do not need to (and should not) supply the order ID of the originating transaction for lookup, and I do not believe it is supported to add new/unique order IDs to refunds.

Comment: I need to match data that get from paypal. so i wanted to simply add an unique parameter. due to paypal docs it is suitable to use optinal invoiceid param. but in reality i had problems. so i did it in another way. i have used the transaction id paypal returned for matching.

Answer (score 0):

due to paypal docs it is suitable to use optinal invoiceid param. but in reality i had problems. so i did it in another way. i have used the transaction id paypal returned for matching.